# Wrong result when formatting decimals as percentages with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I have a macro that uses the siunitx package to format decimal numbers as percentages. It looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\perc[1]{\qty[round-mode = places, round-precision = 1,
                        exponent-mode = fixed, fixed-exponent = 0]{#1e2}{\percent}}

\begin{document}
\perc{0.3}
\perc{0.045}
\perc{0}
\end{document}
```

For `\perc{0.3}` and `\perc{0.045}`, this produces `30.0%` and `4.5%` as intended. However, it fails for 0: `\perc{0}` results in `0.0 × 10^2`. Is this behavior intended by siunitx? Is there a workaround which would give the desired `0.0%` output for 0?

Comment: Does adding `drop-exponent = true` solve the problem?

Comment: I'd use an expression here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `drop-exponent=true` as post-processing option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\perc[1]{\qty[round-mode = places,
                            round-precision = 1,
                            exponent-mode = fixed,
                            fixed-exponent = 0,
                            drop-exponent=true
                        ]{#1e2}{\percent}}

\begin{document}
    \perc{0.3}
    
    \perc{0.045}
    
    \perc{0}
\end{document}
```

[image: a]